# How to use HuggingFace embbedings with Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-search, langchain, py-langchain, openaiembeddings

I'm using langchain with Azure OpenAI and Azure Cognitive Search.
Currently I'm using Azure OpenAI text-embedding-ada-002 model for generating embeddings, but I would like to use a embbeding model from HugginFace if possible, because Azure OpenAI API does not allow to send documents in batches, so I need to make several calls and hit the rate limit.

I tried using this embbeding in my code:

```py
embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(
        model_name="all-mpnet-base-v2",
    )
```

Instead of:

```py
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(
        ...
)
```

The problem I'm facing, is that when I use  AzureSearch's `aadd_texts` method I get this error:

```
The vector field 'content_vector' dimensionality must match the field definition's 'dimensions' property. Expected: '1536'. Actual: '768'. (IndexDocumentsFieldError) 98: The vector field 'content_vector' dimensionality must match the field definition's 'dimensions' property. Expected: '1536'. Actual: '768'.
        Code: IndexDocumentsFieldError
```

I'm pretty lost. Did anyone used an open source embeddings model with Cognitive Search? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure OpenAI API does allow to send documents in batches.

*Input  string or **array** Input text to get embeddings for, encoded as an array or string. The number of input tokens varies depending on what model you are using. Only text-embedding-ada-002 (Version 2) supports array input.*

Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference#embeddings.

Comment: Thanks!
I had errors saying max number of inputs was 1. I'm going to try this

Answer (score 4):

As the error message indicates, there's a mismatch in the dimension of the vector field.

Based on the documentation for `all-mpnet-base-v2` model, the dimension of the vector is 768 (ref: https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2#all-mpnet-base-v2) whereas the default dimension for a vector field created in Azure Search is 1536 (it assumes that you are going to use `text-embedding-ada-002` model from Open AI).

Please check your index definition and make sure that the dimension property of the vector fields is 768. You may need to recreate your index.

Comment: I made a new index with those dimensions and it worked! Thanks